# jQuery height() for an element containing a custom-font text seems inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a single `div` like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="styled">
        Text
    </div>
</body>
```

And our style looks something like:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Liberation Mono'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('LiberationMono-Regular.ttf'); /*local URL to font*/
}

.styled {
    font-size: 200px;
    font-family: "Liberation Mono";
}
```

Now, if we add some Javascript to be executed on document ready (after including jQuery 2.1.4):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log($("div.styled").height())
    });
</script>
```

The value displayed is the console is **243**, but inspecting the `div` with the developper tools, it is actually **227px** high.

Using the default font from the browser (Chrome in our case), the result would be consistent.

Is this expected behaviour ?
Is there a known work around ?

**EDIT:** The font is available for [download from Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=liberation%20mono&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y).

Comment: Did you try .outerHeight()? http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Comment: Works fine for me. I have not tried your font, but I did it with Calibri and I got 243.6.. using Chrome inspect element, but I got 244 using `.height()`.

Comment: @FraserCrosbie Thank you for the suggestions. Both `outerHeight()` and `outerHeight(true)` return the inconsistent value **243**.

Comment: This is because custom fonts aren't loaded at `$.ready`. You need to listen to the `$(window).load()` event instead.

Comment: @Louy That is not a comment, but the right answer ;) If you post it as an answer and I will accept it (and thank you for the spot-on help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because custom fonts aren't loaded at `$.ready`. You need to listen to the `$(window).load()` event instead.